# Program fails to continue running after break; in loop

Tags: java, loops

I have created a login system for an elevator that requires authentication that currently works fine. The problem I am having is that the program does not continue running after successful login. Failed logins will terminate the program after 3 failed attempts; this also works fine. I believe it has something to do with either my `break;` line or my bracket placement. I have tried using `continue;` instead but that did not work either. The next part of the code simply does not run after login and no errors are given.

Here is my code;

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int UserID = 5555; 
    final int Password = 1234;
    final int StudentNumber = 22334455;

    int EnteredUserID; 
    int EnteredPassword;
    int EnteredStudentNumber;
    for (int s = 0; s <= 3; s++) { 
        if (s < 3) { 
            System.out.println("Enter your UserID to access lift;"); 
            EnteredUserID = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Your UserID is ==> " + EnteredUserID);
            System.out.println("Enter your password to authenticate login;");
            EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Password Entered is ==> " + EnteredPassword);
            System.out.println("Enter your student number to finalise login and authentication;");
            EnteredStudentNumber = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Student Number Entered is ==> " + EnteredStudentNumber);
            if (UserID == EnteredUserID && (Password == EnteredPassword) 
                    && (StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber)) {
                System.out.println("Athentication complete!");
                System.out.println("***Elevator access granted!***");
                System.out.println("Welcome..."); 
                break;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong UserID, Password or Student Number. Please try again."); 
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("3 incorrect enteries detected. Access Denied!"); 
        }
    }
}


    private int currentFloor;

    public Elevator() {
        currentFloor = 0;
    }

    public void selectFloor() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int newFloor;

        System.out.println("Enter your destination floor ==> ");
        newFloor = scnr.nextInt();
        if (newFloor > 7 || newFloor < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid floor entry");
        }

        else {  
            int direction = 0;
            if(currentFloor < newFloor){
                direction = 1; 
            } else if (currentFloor > newFloor) {
                direction = -1; ;
            } else {
                direction = 0; 
            }
            for (; currentFloor != newFloor; currentFloor += newFloor)
                System.out.println("..." + currentFloor);
                System.out.println("Elevator has arrived!");
        }
    }

    public void fireAlarm() {
        System.out.println("***FIRE ALARM*** Please exit the building safely.");


}

}
```

I'm probably missing something really simple but just can't seem to find it.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to go after the authentication? You are currently breaking out of the loop, which sends it to the code below, but... there is no code below.

Comment: There's no code after the `for` loop. Break leaves the loop. So it does nothing but exit the program.

Comment: After the break/successful login I wanted the code to begin running from `private int currentFloor;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is you're `breaking` out of the loop. This sends it out of the loop and to the rest of the method, which is empty in this case. You aren't instructing it to do anything. I think what you meant to do was:

```
        if (UserID == EnteredUserID && (Password == EnteredPassword) 
                && (StudentNumber == EnteredStudentNumber)) {
            System.out.println("Athentication complete!");
            System.out.println("***Elevator access granted!***");
            System.out.println("Welcome...");
            Elevator a = new Elevator(); //actually do something
            Elevator.selectfloor();
            break;
        }
```

That is, assuming `Elevator` is a class.

Answer (score 0):

After three failures, the for loop ends, so the method returns and the program exits. On successful login, you break out of the for loop... the method returns and the program exits.

What exactly do you expect to happen on successful login ... and where is the code to make that happen?